# How to separate existing steps in Magento 2 one page checkout?

Tags: magento2, shipping, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout, customize

I need to **customize** the shipping steps into **Account** and **shipping**.

In the **Account section**, I need to show the customer email address only.

In the **Shipping section**, I need to show the shipping address.

How can I achieve this?

> Through any Extension or any reference code?

Anyone share your thought or reference.
[image]

Comment: You have to create extra extension for this, also you can't removed Name and address cause these are required.

Comment: Yes, we need to create an extension, but how to achieve this tell me some reference code or link. I don't want to remove a name. I want an email in one section and name & other details in a separate section.